# Why is $y=Re[\rm{sin}^{-1}(x)]$ flat beyond $z>1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

In the real domain, $\rm{sin}^{-1}(x)$ is undefined for $x>1$ but in the complex world [WolframAlpha produces a flat graph for large inputs](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=re%28arcsin%28z%29%29):

[image]

Throwing in some test values explicitly, wolframAlpha tells me [$Re[\rm{sin}^{-1}(10)]=\frac{\pi}{2}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=re%28arcsin%2810%29%29) and likewise for other large inputs.

I was intuitively expecting extended complex solutions to lie in curves. Why is this function constant for large inputs?

Comment: If $x>1$ real the expression inside the logarithm is purely imaginary (of the type $ic,c>0$) so obviously the argument  (which is the  imaginary part of the logarithm) is $\pi/2$

Comment: Because $\,\sin^{-1}(x) = \sinh^{-1}(x\,i)/i.$